Get Federal User Activity Status Microsoft Graph API
I'm looking for a way to retrieve the activity status of federated users in bulk for external companies via API, without the need to invite the users and wait for them to accept the invitation.
Is it possible to obtain the same activity status response as when using the search bar in Teams, even if not using the Graph API but other methods? Currently, this method only provides an "offline" status or "presence unknown" for all federated users.
Any help or suggestions would be greatly appreciated.
Thank you!
import requests
import json
from dotenv import load_dotenv
from msal import ConfidentialClientApplication


load_dotenv(dotenv_path=r'....')


CLIENT_ID = os.getenv('CLIENT_ID')
CLIENT_SECRET = os.getenv('CLIENT_SECRET')
TENANT_ID = os.getenv('TENANT_ID')

app = ConfidentialClientApplication(
CLIENT_ID,
authority=f"https://login.microsoftonline.com/{TENANT_ID}",
client_credential=CLIENT_SECRET,)

result = app.acquire_token_for_client(scopes=["https://graph.microsoft.com/.default"])

if "access_token" in result:
access_token = result["access_token"]
else:
print("Error acquiring token:", result.get("error"), result.get("error_description"))
exit(1)

user_id = "..."

presence_url = f'https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/communications/presences/{user_id}'
presence_headers = {
'Authorization': f'Bearer {access_token}',
'Content-Type': 'application/json'}

response = requests.get(presence_url, headers=presence_headers)

if response.status_code == 200:
presence_info = response.json()
print("Presence Info:", json.dumps(presence_info, indent=2))

else:
print("Failed to retrieve presence info:", response.status_code, response.text)


Graph API to get presence does not work for External users. There is no other workaround for this.

I agree with @Meghana-MSFT, by default it is not possible to fetch presence for External users using Microsoft Graph API. Refer this SO Thread by @alphaz18.

External users like those on Teams but not in your organization system have restricted information access through tools like Microsoft Graph API.
However, guest users, even though they're external, allow for detailed reporting and full access to their activities within your organization setup.

I got the same response for External user:
# Initialize the ConfidentialClientApplication
app = ConfidentialClientApplication(
    CLIENT_ID,
    authority=f"https://login.microsoftonline.com/{TENANT_ID}",
    client_credential=CLIENT_SECRET
)

# Acquire token for client
result = app.acquire_token_for_client(scopes=["https://graph.microsoft.com/.default"])

if "access_token" in result:
    access_token = result["access_token"]
else:
    print("Error acquiring token:", result.get("error"), result.get("error_description"))
    exit(1)

# User ID for whom presence information is to be retrieved
user_id = "UserID"  # Replace with the actual user ID

# Presence endpoint URL
presence_url = f'https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/communications/presences/{user_id}'
presence_headers = {
    'Authorization': f'Bearer {access_token}',
    'Content-Type': 'application/json'
}

# Send request to Microsoft Graph API
response = requests.get(presence_url, headers=presence_headers)

if response.status_code == 200:
    presence_info = response.json()
    print("Presence Info:", json.dumps(presence_info, indent=2))
else:
    print("Failed to retrieve presence info:", response.status_code, response.text)



The Microsoft Graph API's /presence endpoint, when accessed using application permissions such as Presence.Read or Presence.Read.All,  does not allow fetching presence data for external users.
This is by design to enforce privacy and security measures, ensuring that presence information of users external to your organization cannot be accessed without specific consent.

Reference:
Guest/external users showing offline - not able to connect - Microsoft Community
